# magento 2 observer for change shipping amount on checkout

Tags: magento2, checkout

which event used for changing shipping amount on checkout ?
i want to change shipping amount on checkout if customer change city or state 
i already used `sales_order_shipment_save_before` but it doesn't worked

Comment: Hi, you get any solution?

Comment: @RajanSoni yeah i found but i did not remember ....it is for 9 month ago ...sorry